# mongodb unexpected shutdown with unsuccessful repair

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I was running mongodb as a daemon and running various scripts in crontab which were using mongodb.

I had an enexpected shutdown and thereafter I tried to rerun it using the repair mode but unfortunately had the following response. What measures can I take to recover the database and relaunch the same as a daemon?

```
siddharta@0data:/var/lib/mongodb$ sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --repair --repairpath /var/lib/mongodb0
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12379 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=0data
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.4, pdfile version 4.5
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lamiak 2.6.42-37-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:28:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_46_1
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", repair: true, repairpath: "/var/lib/mongodb0" }
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] recover begin
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] info no lsn file in journal/ directory
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] recover lsn: 0
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] recover /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._16
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] recover create file /var/lib/mongodb/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/boardreader.ns 16MB
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/$tmp_repairDatabase_0
Tue Oct 29 17:37:38 [initandlisten] recover create file /var/lib/mongodb/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/boardreader.0 64MB
Tue Oct 29 17:37:39 [initandlisten] recover create file /var/lib/mongodb/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/boardreader.1 128MB
Tue Oct 29 17:37:43 [initandlisten] recover cleaning up
Tue Oct 29 17:37:43 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Tue Oct 29 17:37:43 [initandlisten] recover done
Tue Oct 29 17:37:43 [initandlisten] preallocating a journal file /var/lib/mongodb/journal/prealloc.0
                283115520/1073741824    26%
                398458880/1073741824    37%
                534773760/1073741824    49%
                713031680/1073741824    66%
                901775360/1073741824    83%
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [initandlisten] ****
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [initandlisten] ****
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database rezagm with pdfile version 4.5, new version: 4.5
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [initandlisten]      starting upgrade
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [initandlisten]  rezagm repairDatabase rezagm
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [initandlisten] query rezagm.system.namespaces nscanned:7 nreturned:7 reslen:277 259ms
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb0/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/rezagm.ns, filling with zeroes...
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb0/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb0/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/rezagm.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0.001 secs
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb0/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/rezagm.0, filling with zeroes...
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb0/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/rezagm.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.014 secs
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb0/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/rezagm.1, filling with zeroes...
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb0/$tmp_repairDatabase_0/rezagm.1, size: 128MB,  took 0.003 secs
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [initandlisten] query rezagm.tweetbase nscanned:7 nreturned:7 reslen:335029 231ms
Tue Oct 29 17:38:04 [initandlisten] build index rezagm.tweetbase { _id: 1 }
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] build index done 7 records 0.077 secs
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] warning: ClientCursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns: rezagm.favorite_det top: { opid: 4, active: true, waitingForLock: false, secs_running: 0, op: "getmore", ns: "rezagm.favorite_det", query: {}, client: "0.0.0.0:0", desc: "initandlisten", threadId: "0x7f95b479a740", numYields: 0 }
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] warning: ClientCursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns: rezagm.favorite_det top: { opid: 4, active: true, waitingForLock: false, secs_running: 0, op: "getmore", ns: "rezagm.favorite_det", query: {}, client: "0.0.0.0:0", desc: "initandlisten", threadId: "0x7f95b479a740", numYields: 0 }
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] warning: ClientCursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns: rezagm.favorite_det top: { opid: 4, active: true, waitingForLock: false, secs_running: 0, op: "getmore", ns: "rezagm.favorite_det", query: {}, client: "0.0.0.0:0", desc: "initandlisten", threadId: "0x7f95b479a740", numYields: 0 }
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] warning: ClientCursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns: rezagm.favorite_det top: { opid: 4, active: true, waitingForLock: false, secs_running: 0, op: "getmore", ns: "rezagm.favorite_det", query: {}, client: "0.0.0.0:0", desc: "initandlisten", threadId: "0x7f95b479a740", numYields: 0 }
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] build index rezagm.favorite_det { _id: 1 }
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] build index done 633 records 0.003 secs
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] build index rezagm.progression { _id: 1 }
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] build index done 98 records 0.003 secs
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten]   Assertion failure _recovering db/dur_recover.cpp 235
0x56e0a3 0x56c9f3 0x574639 0x6cb1b3 0x6cb655 0x6cb835 0x6cc0a0 0x6c766a 0x6c7b03 0x6c137d 0x6be9c4 0x6beb9e 0x7839ca 0x77420d 0x7940d5 0x8926b3 0x8946f4 0x895448 0x5281f0 0x7f95b2ad576d
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x23) [0x56e0a3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12sayDbContextEPKc+0xc3) [0x56c9f3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8assertedEPKcS1_j+0xf9) [0x574639]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11RecoveryJob5writeERKNS0_18ParsedJournalEntryE+0x543) [0x6cb1b3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11RecoveryJob10applyEntryERKNS0_18ParsedJournalEntryEbb+0x235) [0x6cb655]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11RecoveryJob12applyEntriesERKSt6vectorINS0_18ParsedJournalEntryESaIS3_EE+0x65) [0x6cb835]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11RecoveryJob14processSectionEPKNS0_11JSectHeaderEPKvjPKNS0_11JSectFooterE+0x640) [0x6cc0a0]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur22WRITETODATAFILES_Impl1ERKNS0_11JSectHeaderERNS_14AlignedBuilderE+0x8a) [0x6c766a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur16WRITETODATAFILESERKNS0_11JSectHeaderERNS_14AlignedBuilderE+0x43) [0x6c7b03]
 mongod() [0x6c137d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8MongoMMF5closeEv+0x34) [0x6be9c4]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8MongoMMFD1Ev+0x2e) [0x6beb9e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8DatabaseD2Ev+0x4a) [0x7839ca]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database13closeDatabaseEPKcRKSs+0x22d) [0x77420d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14repairDatabaseESsRSsbb+0x3b5) [0x7940d5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11doDBUpgradeERKSsSsPNS_14DataFileHeaderE+0x63) [0x8926b3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi+0x7a4) [0x8946f4]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x18) [0x895448]
 mongod(main+0x2770) [0x5281f0]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f95b2ad576d]
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] dbexception in groupCommit causing immediate shutdown: 0 assertion db/dur_recover.cpp:235
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 gc1
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 Backtrace:
0x56e0a3 0x8913dc 0x7f95b2aea4a0 0x7f95b2aea425 0x7f95b2aedb8b 0x77123e 0x6c14f7 0x6be9c4 0x6beb9e 0x7839ca 0x77420d 0x7940d5 0x8926b3 0x8946f4 0x895448 0x5281f0 0x7f95b2ad576d 0x529861
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x23) [0x56e0a3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x34c) [0x8913dc]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0) [0x7f95b2aea4a0]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x7f95b2aea425]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x17b) [0x7f95b2aedb8b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10mongoAbortEPKc+0x3e) [0x77123e]
 mongod() [0x6c14f7]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8MongoMMF5closeEv+0x34) [0x6be9c4]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8MongoMMFD1Ev+0x2e) [0x6beb9e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8DatabaseD2Ev+0x4a) [0x7839ca]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database13closeDatabaseEPKcRKSs+0x22d) [0x77420d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14repairDatabaseESsRSsbb+0x3b5) [0x7940d5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11doDBUpgradeERKSsSsPNS_14DataFileHeaderE+0x63) [0x8926b3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi+0x7a4) [0x8946f4]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x18) [0x895448]
 mongod(main+0x2770) [0x5281f0]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f95b2ad576d]
 mongod() [0x529861]

Logstream::get called in uninitialized state
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] ERROR: Client::~Client _context should be null but is not; client:initandlisten
Logstream::get called in uninitialized state
Tue Oct 29 17:38:05 [initandlisten] ERROR: Client::shutdown not called: initandlisten
```

Does too many long lasting crons could shutdown the mongodb daemon?

Comment: If I recall correctly this could be related to low disk space or write permissions on disk.Can you try to copy DB files to larger volume and try running repair.

Comment: @rVr I think you saved my life. My VM Memory is 60% full. Ill try to increase the memory and check if it works. For the moment I have stopped all writes to the database. Do you think my data could be damaged due to this?

Comment: There may or may not be data corruption.If you are running as part of a replica set you can restore from backup.Also I was asking to check disk space and write permissions.You may check memory as well.